# Dictionary input parameter of a WCF method not receiving the value

Tags: c#, wcf, postman, .net-4.6

I declared a method like this:

```cs
public int MyFunc(int x1, Dictionary<string, string> x2 , string x3 , Guid x4)
```

and I sended a request from Postman with this body:

```json
{
   
"x1" : "1",
"x2" : {
        "IsRevisit": true,
        "key2": "value2"
       },
"x3" : "test",
"x4" : "A3E133EA-A692-482A-837A-0BDC9F2D0536"
}
```

**Problem** :
x1, x3 and x4 are receiving their value but nothing for x2. I put break point on the line:
[image]
[image]

**Solutions didn't work**

- I declared the method like this:

```cs
public int MyFunc(int x1, Dictionary<string, object> x2 , string x3 , Guid x4)
```

- I sended dictionary like this:         `"IsRevisit": "true"`

Eventually, I declared a structure similar to a dictionary to accomplish what I intended. However, I'm encountering this problem of receiving the value. Why it's happening?

**Project Information**

- WCF Service
- .net framework 4.6
- Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6.2

Answer (score 0):

To catch the specific error you got, you may use [WCF Trace Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing).

We need to know what type are we passing so that it can deserialise that object in wcf. So WCF is strongly typed.

> public int MyFunc(int x1, Dictionary<string, object> x2 , string x3 ,
> Guid x4)

The WCF will throw Exception because `public int MyFunc(Dictionary<string, object> x2)`  catch all type defined that WCF can not deserialise.

You may define a method like below :

```
 [OperationContract]
     int Method(MyClass myClassObject);
```

And put it like this `Dictionary<string,myClassObject>`.Then it will work.